# Composite primary key: Finding one attribute using another

Tags: sql, database

## Data fields

I am designing a database table structure. Say that we need to record employee profiles from different companies. We have the following fields:

```
+---------+--------------+-----+--------+-----+
| Company | EmployeeName | Age | Gender | Tel |
+---------+--------------+-----+--------+-----+
```

It's possible that two employees from different company may have the same name (and assume that no 2 employee has the same name in the same company). In this case a composite primary key `(Company, EmployeeName)` would be necessary in my opinion.

## Search

Now I need to get all information by using only one of the 2 attributes in the primary key. For example,
I want to search all employees' profile of Company A:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Age, Gender, Tel FROM table WHERE Company = 'Company A'
```

And I can also search all employees from different company named Donald:

```
SELECT Company, Age, Gender, Tel FROM table WHERE EmployeeName = 'Donald'
```

## Strategy

In order to implement this requirement, my strategy would be storing all data in a single table, which is easy to read and understandable. However I noticed that it may take a long time to search as the query may need to iterate through all rows. I would like to retrieve these information as quick as possible. Would there be a better strategy for this?

Answer (score 1):

First, your rows should have a unique identifier for each row -- identity/auto-increment/serial, depending on the database.  Second, you might reconsider names being unique.  Why can't two people at the same company have the same name?

In any case, you have a primary key on, say, `(company, name)`.  For the opposite search you simply want another index on `(name, company)`:

```
create index idx_profiles_name_company on profiles(name, company);
```

Answer (score 0):

A note explaining Gordon's suggestion for an identity on each row.  This is supplemental to his answer above.

In theory there is nothing wrong with a primary key that crosses columns and in a db like PostgreSQL I like to have identity values as secondary keys (i.e. not null unique) and specify natural primary keys.  Of course on MS SQL Server or MySQL/InnoDB that would be a recipe for problems.  I would also not say "all" but rather "almost all" since there are times when breaking this rule is good.

Regardless, having an identity row simplifies a couple of things and it provides an abstraction around keys in case you get things wrong.  Composite keys provide a couple issues that end up eating time (and possibly resulting in downtime) later.  These include:

1. Joins on composite keys are often more expensive than those on simple values, and
2. Adding or changing a natural primary key which crosses columns is far harder when joins are involved

So depending on your db you should either specify a unique secondary key or make your natural primary key separate (which you should do depends on storage and implementation specifics).